# How to prove this expression?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

It's from a programming language. "%' here is a modulo operation.

```
(a * 2^32 + b) % c = (((a % c) * (2^32 % c)) + b) % c
```

Comment: So, what you want to prove is that $a\cdot b(\mod c)=(a(\mod c)\cdot b(\mod c))(\mod c)$ and the same holds for addition, correct?

Comment: Mmm, probably right :) But I'm not a mathematician, so I would be glad to take a look at some basic articles on this theme.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you have two integers

```
a = j + kc
b = l + mc
```

Then

```
ab % c
= (j+kc)(l+mc) % c 
= (jl + jmc + lkc + kmc^2) % c
= jl
= (a % c)(b % c)
```

Comment: And the same for sums.

Comment: "jl + jmc + lkc + kmc^2 % c" - does '%' relate only to the last term? Why? And why this equals to 'jl'?

Comment: Just like (1+2+4+6)/2=(1/2)+1+2+3 (look at the parentheses), (jl + jmc + lkc + kmc^2) / c=(jl/c)+jm+lk+kmc. Think about what that means about (jl + jmc + lkc + kmc^2) % c.